# OpenCV Not Writing File

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to create a video from still images all in a folder. The file that is written is 0KB in size. I have checked and all files are retrieved by the glob.glob part correctly(That's what the commented print(filename) line is about). I have tried multiple fourcc options and none of them work. Does anyone see an issue that would be causing this? Also this is running on python 3 in Jupyter Notebook.

```
fold_file = fold +'/*jpg' #fold is just the path to folder containing the images
img_array=[]
for filename in glob.glob(fold_file):
    #print(filename)
    img=cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layer = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    img_array.append(img)

out = cv2.VideoWriter('pleasework.avi',cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('X','V','I','D') ,15,size)

for image in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(image)


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
out.release()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, I would recommend using pathlib for all your path manipulation needs.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code is probably your issue:

```
for image in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(image)
```

The `len()` function counts the number of items in a sequence. Let's presume, for sake of argument that you have five images in `img_array`. Then `len()` would return `5`. We are then feeding that length value into the `range()` function to produce a sequence of numbers from `0` to `4` (i.e. up to but not including 5).

We are then parsing through that range using the `for` loop, and we are dropping the numbers `0` through `4` into the `out.write()` method instead of dropping in images.

What you probably want is this:

```
for image in img_array:
    out.write(image)
```

`img_array` is a Python `list` and as such, can be parsed by `for` loops natively without having to use any sort of length calculation, etc.

Comment: Thanks! That did make the file actually have a size. However I keep getting an error saying "Choose something else to play. This item is in a format we don't support." while trying to play back the video. Any tips on this situation?